# CSS style not apply to TextBox in GridView ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, textbox, itemtemplate

I have a `TextBox` in a `GridView` `ItemTemplate`. I added `css` style to it using `CssClass="txtboxAlignRight"`. but when i run my page, style is not applied.

I have an another `TextBox` in a `GridView` `FooterTemplate`. i added this style to that `TextBox` also. it's working properly. but `TextBox` in  `GridView` `ItemTemplate` is not applying this style.

How can i solve this ?

**Css**

```
.txtboxAlignRight
{    
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;         

}
```

**aspx page**

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_cc" Width="150" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("COUNT") %>'
        CssClass="txtboxAlignRight"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you provide both the css class you are using and a little snippet of the page where that is declared? that might help to see what's wrong :)

Comment: @CarlosB there are no errors with declaration or css class. because it is working properly in `FooterTemplate`.

Comment: so none of the style is applied when the page is rendered. Ok did you define any gridview event that might alter the rows somehow? like onRowDataBound?

Comment: @CarlosB no. no any gridview event.

Comment: The only thing i can remember at this point is the rendering process of the gridview eliminating your css definition (not translating to class="txtboxAlignRight"), to debug this try and check the html present on the browser (but frankly i'm a bit out of ideas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added below code in to my `css` file.

```
input[type="text"]
{   
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
}
```

This apply style to all text boxes in my page. then i added `Style="text-align: right"` to `TextBox` in my `ItemTemplate`.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_cc" Width="150" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("COUNT") %>'
        Style="text-align: right"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line in your templatefield.

**ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"**